# How to setup MX Record?

Tags: linux, email, dns, gnu

I am trying to setup a mail server in my PC for my LAN network and I opted for Postfix but  the configuration ask me to configure the MX Record, something about DNS configuration but I have no idea of how to proceed...Can you help me please? Is necessary to create a DNS account in some DNS server or something like? Thanks in advance!

PS: OS: GNU/Linux Debian squeeze

Comment: Theoretically you can put an IP address or a host name after the @ symbol in an email address, but this is so rarely used. You will need to actually own a domain name and setup an MX record for it so you can actually send/receive email on the Internet.

Comment: Do you think a free DNS account can be useful? I have no money... :(

Comment: Not SU question

Comment: What are you trying to do with your mail server? MX server is needed whenever you have a domain name and want to inform the world where the emails for that domain should be sent to. If you have your email delivered somewhere else (eg gmail), then you don't need an mx record.

Comment: @billc.cn: `@[ip.addr]` is more or less obsolete, and often rejected for security reasons; however, `@host` is still standard -- when no MX records are found, the A/AAAA records are required to be used.

Comment: @D.D.C: DynDNS and FreeDNS.afraid.org both allow configuring MX records.

Comment: I need send and receive mail within a LAN with my PC acting as Server.

Comment: For you Googlers using bind9, the file is /etc/bind/db.localdomain

Answer (score 5):

Yes, an [MX record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) is part of your organization's [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) setup. It's not part of your *computer*'s setup: DNS records are what tell other computers how to reach your computer, and the MX record is used when they want to send you email.

When a computer sends an email to `joe@somewhere.example.com`, it looks up the MX record for `somewhere.example.com`. You can look up the MX records for a host name with commands like `dig -t MX somewhere.example.com` or `host -t MX somewhere.example.com` (and the `host` command with no option also lists MX records, with the wording “somewhere.example.com mail is handled by …”).

If you only want to be able to send email inside your LAN, you need to set up an MX record on the DNS server from your LAN. That's probably the same machine that you've configured as a DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf`. These are technically two different functions, one is a DNS server returning information from its own database and the other is really a DNS proxy that forwards queries to the appropriate destination, but they are usually provided together. Contact your DNS server's administrator, or if that's you and you don't know what to do, tell us what you're using for a DNS server.

If you want to send email from elsewhere, you need a public-facing MX record. Most DNS providers, even cheap ones, let you set up MX records in addition to A records (machine names).

Comment: A local DNS hee... It can be in the same machine where the mail server is installed?

Comment: @D.D.C It can be, yes. It's common, in fact, in small organizations, to have a single machine that handles all internal server functions (DNS, file sharing, mail, …). What you need to keep in mind is that all computers that send mail to `somewhere.example.com` must be able to find this information.

Comment: Ok, right now I am looking for how to configure a Local DNS, I hope succeed. I get back later. Thanks!

Comment: @Giles: "...a single machine that handles all internal server functions..." So true. I saw one office that had two.  The physical machine's host OS also hosted a guest VM running DNS.

Comment: I have been trying configure a DNS Server without success. I have installed **bind9** but every tutorial say me something different. Can you help me? Some good tutorial? Please! If it's not too much to ask.

Comment: @D.D.C Bind is powerful but not the easiest DNS server to configure. If your network is very simple, you might prefer another program. I use dnsmasq for my home network.